# Windows cant see my android phone. SM-J200F

Tags: samsung, hardware, mtp

I reinstall my windows today, and i try to install my phone drivers. when installing drivers I accidentally closed automatic driver install window. So, i try to reinstall but not work. I tried installing Samsung official drivers from their website, it install successfully but not connect to Kies or Smart Switch (samsung new software) so i cant browse my phone files..
I tried remove all drivers about samsung and android then cleaned temp files, and run Cclaner for registry fix, still i cant see my phone..

I think need full removal also from Registry but i dont know how to.

Can someone help me for fix this?

Thanks!

(sorry for my bad english..)

Comment: Let me guess: Windows 10? Just this morning I've read Samsung warning its users their drivers having issues with Win10.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the automatic driver installation, just open the Windows Device Manager, select your phone (if it shows up) and click on 'Update Driver Software'.